# "Unable to Load Asset" for PDF's in Form Recognizer Labeling Tool

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

Form Recognizer shows 'unable to load asset' on PDFs. I have tried multiple PDF's from various sources and they all return this error. JPGs work as expected.

An additional error popped up

> Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on
> 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at
> 'http://fotts.azureedge.net/npm/pdfjs-dist/2.3.200/pdf.worker.js'
> failed to load

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/microsoft/OCR-Form-Tools/issues/819

Comment: I am experiencing the same error. I use the local environment (http://localhost:3000) in the current versions to train my model via docker (docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/custom-form/labeltool:latest). I get the error: Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://fotts.azureedge.net/npm/pdfjs-dist/2.3.200/pdf.worker.js' failed to load. This environment worked like this until a few days ago with the same configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Form Recognizer sample tool version are you using ? Do you get this error also on the latest release - http://fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: this was it, I was using an older docker version. Running the code from github (2.1) made all the difference! Works like a charm :)